# The possible "cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01722: invalid number" reason of retrieve data from oracle by cx_oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have one basic SQL :

```sql
select * from my_schema.table
```

when I run this in Dbeaver, can return data without problem, but when I use python cx_Oracle， will runs into

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01722: invalid number

```py
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
import sqlalchemy

con_str = f'oracle://{user}:{passwd}@{dsn}'
conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine(con_str)
aa = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * FROM my_schema.table''', conn)
```

from my understanding, there is no string convert operation which is the reason of the `ORA-01722`

I even use ojdbc in R, also result is `ORA-01722`

I use same method read other table, without any issue.

If I limit the result in to 1 or 2 lines(add 'where rownum < 2'), the data is normal, that means the problem data is in row 2 ??.

I checked the data, all normal, this table are generated by other table in same server.

Where should I start to debug the issue?  pls anyone give me any hint.

I know I should paste the data to regenerate the issue, but the data is confidential, so I can't, sorry for that.

run out of idea.

Comment: SQL table have no any row order, so there's no N'th rowing the table, which may cause the issue. You should provide **minimal** reproducible example: find the least number of (any) rows and columns that can reproduce the issue. You do not need to post sensitive data

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your `my_schema.table` is a "view" really. Just check it. And the easiest  way to check it is to check execution plan.

Comment: Try the query with SQL*Plus.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov: indeed, the my_schema.table is a "view", but I checked some of other views, no one has  such issue, only the view I try to retrieve data has such issue.

Comment: @astentx oracle automatically adds rownum for sql result based on default sequence, the syntax "limit 2" not working for oracle.  -----my understanding

Comment: as I said: check your execution plan and you will find string conversion functions in it.

Comment: re "no one has such issue" - so other users/programs have other NLS settings.

Comment: If you have the same error in cx_Oracle and ojdbc then it sounds like corrupt data in the DB.

Comment: @ChristopherJones yes, that is also my thought, but I can get the data from Dbweaver, which also through ojdbc, that is the main reason I lost my mind